# php array_search 0 index

Tags: php, arrays, search, zero

It seems that that you can not use the search_array function in PHP to search the 0 index AND have it evalute as true.

Consider this code for example:

```
$test=array(100, 101, 102, 103);

if($key=array_search(100,$test)){

     echo $key;

}

else{

     echo "Not found";

}
```

The needle '100' is found in the haystack and the key is returned as 0. So far so good, but then when I evaluate whether the search was successful or not it fails because the returned value is 0, equal to false!

The php manual suggests using '!==' but by doing so the key (array index) is not returned, instead either 1 or 0 is returned:

```
if($key=(array_search(103,$test)!== false)){

}
```

So how can I successfully search the array, find a match in the 0 index and have it evaluate as true?

Comment: Did you not see the [BIG RED BOX](http://php.net/array_search#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues)? Try to read the documentation and understand the language before you ask such questions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is explicitly mentioned in the docs. You need to use `===` or `!==`:

```
$key = array_search(...);

if ($key !== false) ...
```

Otherwise, when `$key` is `0`, which [evaluates to `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) when tested as a boolean.

Comment: You could of course use `if( ($key = array_search(...)) !== false)`

Comment: I read several threads on this, read the manual over and over but couldn't find the answer. I think I had the '!==' in the wrong part of my code. Now working - thanks!

Comment: but in this manner if I use code like if(array_search(...) === true), then why it is not working. (=== true is also string comparison) can anybody explain me

Comment: @EstailSe Your code makes no sense. `array_search` can never return boolean `true`, so no, it will not work, and it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: okay I got your point! thanks, I was comparing index number with Boolean, there I was wrong!

Answer (score 5):

The conditional in your second example block gives execution order priority to the `!==` operator, you want to do the opposite though.

```
if (($key = array_search(100,$test)) !== false) {
```

`!==` has **higher** precedence than `==` which makes the parentheses necessary.

Comment: Note: This is the most correct in here. If I could transfer the upvotes from my awful, old, naive, now-deleted answer I would.

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = array_search($what, $array);
if($key !== false and $array[$key] == $what) {
 return true;
}
```

it's more secure

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($key = array_search(103,$test)) !== false){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test=array(100, 101, 102, 103);

if (($key = array_search(100,$test)) === false) {
    echo "Not found";
} else{
    echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Important**: array_search has a 'STRICT' 3rd parameter to enforce a better search for difficult things like differ '0' from '00' but the point here is that:

The right test to confirm NOT FOUND is === or !== FALSE.

Some other functions in php you must compare the result with FALSE (===) to have a secure "not found". FALSE is equivalent to -1 from other languages (js/java)

```
if( strpos('Haystack', 'Hay') === FALSE){  // it is index 0 too...
   die('Not found');
} else {
   echo 'It is the string index ( 0 > -1 and !== FALSE )';
}
```